# How to change the language with with moment.local?

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I used moment.js to get my date. But when i used moment.local, the language stayed in english and doesn't switch in french when my phone is just in french.

Do you have any solution ?

```
<Text
              style={{
                color: 'white',
                textAlign: 'center',
                marginTop: 20,
                fontSize: 17,
                fontFamily: 'Ambit-Black',
              }}>
              {I18n.t('Dashboard.Le')} {moment(element.dateMatch).local(['fr-FR','en-GB']).format('ll')}
            </Text>
```

Answer (score 1):

MomentJS is **deprecated** and should **not** be used, we switched to dayjs which seems to be solid a much smaller package size and works well, a little bit of hacking away and learning the syntax and you should be set.  it says even on their current page.

https://day.js.org

https://momentjs.com

https://terodox.tech/migrating-away-from-momentjs-part1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to import single locale in your file

```
import moment from 'moment'
import 'moment/locale/en'  // without this line it didn't work
import 'moment/locale/fr'
moment(element.dateMatch).local(['fr','en']).format('ll')
```